# How to use TransactionScope in .NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asynchronous

In my API controller I have code like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult<TransactionDto>> CreateNewTrasaction(TransactionDto accountCreateDto)
{
    var commandModel = _mapper.Map<TransactionHistory>(accountCreateDto);
    _transactionRepository.CreateTransaction(commandModel);

    var accountReadDto = _mapper.Map<AccountReadDto>(commandModel);

    return Ok();
}
```

And inside the `transactionRepository` class, I did the following:

```
private readonly TransactionContext _transContext;

public TransactionRp(TransactionContext tContext)
{
    _transContext = tContext;
}

public async Task CreateTransaction(TransactionHistory transaction)
{
    using(IDbContextTransaction transactionContext = _transContext.Database.BeginTransaction())
    {
        try
        {
            transaction.CreatedDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
            _transContext.TransactionHistories.Add(transaction);
            await _transContext.SaveChangesAsync();

            var senderAccount = _transContext.Accounts.FirstOrDefault(x => x.AccountNo == transaction.AccountNo);
            var receiverAccount = _transContext.Accounts.FirstOrDefault(x => x.AccountNo == transaction.ReceiverAccount);

            senderAccount.Amount = senderAccount.Amount - transaction.Amount;
            receiverAccount.Amount = senderAccount.Amount + transaction.Amount;

            _transContext.Accounts.Update(receiverAccount);
            _transContext.Accounts.Update(receiverAccount);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

But when I run the code, I'm getting an error on this line

```
await _transContext.SaveChangesAsync();
```

And the error is:

> Cannot access a disposed context instance.
> A common cause of this error is disposing a context instance that was resolved from dependency injection and then later trying to use the same context instance elsewhere in your application.
> This may occur if you are calling 'Dispose' on the context instance, or wrapping it in a using statement. If you are using dependency injection, you should let the dependency injection container take care of disposing context instances.
>
> Object name: 'TransactionContext'

**Updated**

This is how I mange context inside `ConfigureServices`

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<TransactionContext>(opt => opt.UseSqlServer
        (Configuration.GetConnectionString("BankConnection"))
    );
}
```

Comment: You don’t show how  _transContext is managed.  Is it DI?

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft  Updated code, Im new to .net core. I think that's what u asked

Comment: Why do you want to use TransactionScope in the first place? If you use EF Core or a similar ORM, changes are cached and only persisted to the database when `SaveChanges` is called at the very end of a request. You don't need explicit transactions, DbContext itself gives you transaction semantics. If you call `SaveChanges` multiple times ... don't. Not without a very serious reason at least

Comment: And if you want distributed transactions they are not supported in .Net core. And BTW, you are not awaiting the Task which means there is no guarantee when the operation is actually processed.  (it's probably after the initial call ends which is why you are getting the disposed errror.)

Answer (score 2):

Seems the problem is with the controller. use `await` with `async` method. `async` keyword is used to make a function asynchronous. The `await` keyword will ask the execution to wait until the defined task gets executed. [Read more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/await)

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult<TransactionCreateDto>> CreateNewTrasaction(TransactionCreateDto accountCreateDto)
{
    var commandModel = _mapper.Map<TransactionHistory>(accountCreateDto);
    await _trasactionRepository.CreateTransaction(commandModel);
    var accountReadDto = _mapper.Map<AccountReadDto>(commandModel);
    return Ok();
}
```